# Aurelia modify text by calling function in HTML

Tags: aurelia

I am new in Aurelia. I am getting data from the server and need to modify text it while populating in html. I am trying it by following code.

```
<span textcontent.bind="modifytext(text)" ></span>
```

Please help me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a variable in your ViewModel (js/ts) to hold your text.
and then you can bind to it in the `html`

`<span>${myVar}</span>`

now in the js - you just assign this variable with the text you want to show.. and thats it.

for array you should use the `repeat.for="i of arr"` binding.
`<div repeat.for="i of arr">${i}</div>`

all of this, and more is explaind in [aurelia.io](https://aurelia.io/docs)

you should read the fundumentals and basic binding techniques -
it's not a lot of reading - and it will help you a lot.

Comment: It is an array and I am running a loop. Do I have to modify that array index before populating or is there any other way like calling a function in HTML?